# Error java.lang.NullPointerException JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using jsf/primefaces, I'm getting this npe, I'm invoking a method "registrar" from a form but appears that I'm doing it wrong.
I have the class ProfesorBean.java and the view edicion.xhtml

```
**Class: ProfesorBean**
...............................................

@ManagedBean(name="profesorBean")
@SessionScoped

public class ProfesorBean {
    private Profesor profesor;
    private List<Profesor> profesores;
    private Integer autogenerado=2;

public String registrar(){
    if (profesor.getCodigo()!=null) {             
    }else {
        profesor.setCodigo(autogenerado);
        profesores.add(profesor);
        autogenerado++;
    }
    profesor=null;
    return "listado";
}

}
...............................................
```

Here is the part of form that is submitted edicion.xhtml

```
...............................................
<f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msjs.form_boton_registrar}" 
                                         action="#{profesorBean.registrar}"
                                         update="@form"
                                         ajax="false"
                                        />
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msjs.form_boton_limpiar}" 
                                         update="panel" 
                                         process="@this"  >
                            <p:resetInput target="panel" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton  action="listado"
                                         value="#{msjs.form_boton_regresar}"
                                         process="@this"
                                         immediate="true"
                                         ajax="false"/>
                    </f:facet>
```

Here is the error

```
FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.FacesException durante el procesamiento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=#{profesorBean.registrar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
FATAL:   #{profesorBean.registrar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{profesorBean.registrar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{profesorBean.registrar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
... 30 more

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 34 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at pe.edu.cibertec.managed.ProfesorBean.registrar(ProfesorBean.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 35 more
```

Comment: can u highlight `ProfesorBean.java` line No.56

Comment: Any time you get an exception of `java.lang.*` package pointing to a line in your own code, then you don't necessarily have a JSF problem, but just a basic Java problem. It's a good learning exercise to try boiling down the problem into a plain Java application class with a `main()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not initializing the member variable `private Profesor profesor`. I don't know what you are trying to do inside registrar. But anyway before using an object it should be initilized.
You are getting NullpointerException since while calling `profesor.getCodigo()` the `profesor` is `null`. Please check it.

Comment: thanks, the list profesores wasn't initialized.